# Problem at installation of blotter package: "blotter has a non-zero exit status"

Tags: r, package, installation

I'm trying to install the package quantstrat, and I realize I need to install blotter first. Then I got the following error message:

my code:

```
install_github("braverock/blotter")
```

The error message:

```
Downloading GitHub repo braverock/blotter@master
Installing 1 packages: quadprog
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/servo/OneDrive/Documentos/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/quadprog_1.5-8.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 54859 bytes (53 KB)
downloaded 53 KB

package ‘quadprog’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\servo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcT8IdK\downloaded_packages
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\servo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcT8IdK\remotes6b3832e71ab8\braverock-blotter-67be2c8/DESCRIPTION' (545ms)
-  preparing 'blotter':
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  cleaning src
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
-  building 'blotter_0.14.8.tar.gz'

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/servo/OneDrive/Documentos/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'blotter' ...
** using staged installation
** libs
C:/RBuildTools/3.5/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c calcPosAvgCost.c -o calcPosAvgCost.o
C:/RBuildTools/3.5/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c init.c -o init.o
C:/RBuildTools/3.5/mingw_64/bin/gcc -shared -s -static-libgcc -o blotter.dll tmp.def calcPosAvgCost.o init.o -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/bin/x64 -lR
installing to C:/Users/servo/OneDrive/Documentos/R/win-library/3.6/00LOCK-blotter/00new/blotter/libs/x64
** R
** data
** demo
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error: (converted from warning) package 'xts' was built under R version 3.6.3
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'blotter'
* removing 'C:/Users/servo/OneDrive/Documentos/R/win-library/3.6/blotter'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/servo/OneDrive/Documentos/R/win-library/3.6/blotter'
Error: Failed to install 'blotter' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/servo/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpcT8IdK/file6b3826d4f8e/blotter_0.14.8.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Anyone has any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

can you tell me about your R version?

I think it'll be `3.6.3` but just want to know it for sure.

Error says, installing `xts` package didn't success, so `blotter` which depends on it failed to install.

So You might install `xts` package first. (Independently)

and try again for install `blotter`.

If it fails again, even `xts` has successfully installed, then show me that error message again.

(Or failed to install `xts` also.)

- R has been updated for **version 4**, considering update for it.